# Bootstrap 3.0.3 & DatePicker not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Yet another problem for me... I decided to remake my website in Bootstrap 3 (3.0.3), most stuff worked smooth until I needed a datepicker.

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1849/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker();
$("#datetimepicker8").on("change.dp",function (e) {
$('#datetimepicker9').data("DateTimePicker").setStartDate(e.date);
});
$("#datetimepicker9").on("change.dp",function (e) {
$('#datetimepicker8').data("DateTimePicker").setEndDate(e.date);
});
});
```

You can see the code in the jsfiddle above and my javascript, something doesn't let me click the icon. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer now but I do have a question, is there a reason  you are enclosing items with '' and "" example being <input type='text' class="form-control" />?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include http://momentjs.com/ first. The datepicker depends on moment.js.

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would be simple!